# Azure Service Bus interoperability between Apache Camel based producer and .NET consumer

Tags: .net-core, apache-camel, interop, azureservicebus, amqp

we're trying to build an event-based integration between an Apache Camel based system with produces messages in an Azure Service Bus topic and an .NET based consumer of these messages.

The producer used the AMQP interface of the Service Bus, while the .NET based consumer uses the current API from Microsoft in namespace `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`.

When we try to access the body in a received message as follows:

```csharp
private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
    try { 
        message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Message.Body);
    }
    catch( Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Body not decoded: Message: {@message}", e.Message);
    }

    _logger.LogInformation("Body Type: {@bodytype}, Content-Type: {@contenttype}, Message: {@message}, Properties: {@properties}", raw.Body.BodyType, args.Message.ContentType, message, args.Message.ApplicationProperties);

    await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
}
```

the following exception is raised:

```
Value cannot be retrieved using the Body property.Use GetRawAmqpMessage to access the underlying Amqp Message object.
System.NotSupportedException: Value cannot be retrieved using the Body property.Use GetRawAmqpMessage to access the underlying Amqp Message object.
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpMessageExtensions.GetBody(AmqpAnnotatedMessage message)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage.get_Body()
```

When peeking the topic with service bus explorer the message looks strange:

```
@string3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�_{"metadata":{"version":"1.0.0","message_id":"AGHcNehoD-hK0pPJCSga9v9sXFwC","message_timestamp":"2022-01-10T13:34:32.778Z"},"data":{"source_timestamp":"2022-01-05T17:20:31.000","material":"101052"}}
```

When messages are sent to another topic with a .NET producer there's a plaintext JSON body in the topic, as expected.

Did anybody successfully build a solution with Azure Service Bus with components based on the two mentioned frameworks, and what did the trick so that interoperability did work? Who can a Camel AMQP producer create messages with a `BodyType` of Data so that the body can be decoded by the .NET Service Bus client libraries without need to use `GetRawAmqpMessage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to what format Camel is using, but that error message indicates that the `Body` that you're trying to decode is not an AMQP data body, which is what the Service Bus client library uses and expects.

In order to read a body that is encoded as an AMQP value or sequence, you'll need to work with the data in AMQP format rather than by using the `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` convenience layer.   To do so, you'll want to call `GetRawAmqpMessage` on the `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`, which will give you back an [AmqpAnnotatedMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.core.amqp.amqpannotatedmessage?view=azure-dotnet).

The annotated message `Body` property will return an [AmqpMessageBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.core.amqp.amqpmessagebody?view=azure-dotnet) instance which will allow you to query the [BodyType](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.core.amqp.amqpmessagebody.bodytype?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Core_Amqp_AmqpMessageBody_BodyType) and retrieve the data in its native format using one of the `TryGet`methods on the `AmqpMessageBody`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `BodyType` seem's to be the issue, as the messages we receive from the Camel component is `Value`.

Comment: That would do it.   `TryGetValue` on `AmqpMessageBody` should be able to read that for you.

Comment: Finally found the solution, with your hints, thanks! The setting for the message-type is somewhat counter-intuitively :-)

Comment: Glad that you found it.   That sounds like a rough one to track down.

Comment: Don't they have a package for this? I used to use the GetBody<T>() method of MessageInterOpExtensions. :(

Answer (score 0):

On our procuder side a SAP Cloud Integration is used, when the `Message Type` parapeter of the AMQP Adapter is set to `Binary`, according to:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/368c481cd6954bdfa5d0435479fd4eaf/Cloud/en-US/d5660c146a93483692335e9d79a8c58f.html.

[image]

This seem to correspond to Apache Camel `jmsMessageType` set to `Bytes`,
see https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/amqp-component.html for details.

The decoding of the body in the `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` works as expected and the `BodyType` is set to `Data`. If using `Text` on the producer side, the `BodyType` will be set to `Value` as described which led to the problems with the decoding of the body.