# How can we consume FHIR type of message from Azure Service bus using Masstransit?

Tags: masstransit

We have NHS 111 adaptor configured locally uses Azure service bus to push data
https://github.com/nhsconnect/integration-adaptor-111
so when we push data from NHS 111 test suite, it sends XML as a payload to adaptor, and adaptor converts message to FHIR type , we are trying to consume message but we are getting error

```
Exception on Receiver sb://[AZURESERVICEBUS]/[QUEUENAME] during ProcessMessageCallback ActiveDispatchCount(0) ErrorRequiresRecycle(True)
System.NotSupportedException: Value cannot be retrieved using the Body property.Use GetRawAmqpMessage to access the underlying Amqp Message object.
   at BinaryData Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpMessageExtensions.GetBody(AmqpAnnotatedMessage message)
   at BinaryData Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceivedMessage.get_Body()
   at new MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.ServiceBusReceiveContext(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ReceiveEndpointContext receiveEndpointContext) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Contexts/ServiceBusReceiveContext.cs:line 21
   at async Task MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.ServiceBusMessageReceiver.Handle(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action<ReceiveContext> contextCallback) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/ServiceBusMessageReceiver.cs:line 49
   at async Task Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor.OnProcessM`your text`essageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
   at async Task Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ReceiverManager.OnMessageHandler(EventArgs args)
   at async Task Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ReceiverManager.ProcessOneMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessage triggerMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Our consume looks like

```
public sealed class Nhs111ClinicalDocumentConsumer : IConsumer<FhirNhs111InboundMessageRegistration>
```

FhirNhs111InboundMessageRegistration is the empty class, I also tried to create class which can represent data same as message, but it also not working

Can anyone help me on this?

I tried with creating FhirNhs111InboundMessageRegistration class with properties

```
using Helix.Nhs.Contracts.V1.Commands;
using Microservice.Contracts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Helix.Nhs.Contracts.V2
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public sealed class Action
    {
        public List<Coding> coding { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Agent
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Author
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Coding
    {
        public string system { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string display { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class ConsentingParty
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Context
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Datum
    {
        public string meaning { get; set; }
        public Reference reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Destination
    {
        public string endpoint { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Encounter
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Entry
    {
        public string fullUrl { get; set; }
        public Resource resource { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public Item item { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Event
    {
        public string system { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string display { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class GeneralPractitioner
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Identifier
    {
        public Type type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Individual
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Item
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Location
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class ManagingOrganization
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Meta
    {
        public DateTime lastUpdated { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class OccurrencePeriod
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class OnBehalfOf
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class OrderedBy
    {
        public List<Coding> coding { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Participant
    {
        public List<Type> type { get; set; }
        public Individual individual { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Patient
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Period
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Practitioner
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class ProvidedBy
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Reason
    {
        public List<Coding> coding { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class ReasonReference
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Recipient
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Reference
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Relationship
    {
        public List<Coding> coding { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Requester
    {
        public Agent agent { get; set; }
        public OnBehalfOf onBehalfOf { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Resource
    {
        public string resourceType { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Event @event { get; set; }
        public List<Destination> destination { get; set; }
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
        public Source source { get; set; }
        public Reason reason { get; set; }
        public object identifier { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public object type { get; set; }
        public Subject subject { get; set; }
        public List<Participant> participant { get; set; }
        public Period period { get; set; }
        public List<Location> location { get; set; }
        public ServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; }
        public bool? active { get; set; }
        public object name { get; set; }
        public ManagingOrganization managingOrganization { get; set; }
        public object address { get; set; }
        public List<Telecom> telecom { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string birthDate { get; set; }
        public List<GeneralPractitioner> generalPractitioner { get; set; }
        public ProvidedBy providedBy { get; set; }
        public string intent { get; set; }
        public string priority { get; set; }
        public Context context { get; set; }
        public OccurrencePeriod occurrencePeriod { get; set; }
        public DateTime? authoredOn { get; set; }
        public Requester requester { get; set; }
        public List<Recipient> recipient { get; set; }
        public List<ReasonReference> reasonReference { get; set; }
        public List<SupportingInfo> supportingInfo { get; set; }
        public bool? doNotPerform { get; set; }
        public object code { get; set; }
        public Encounter encounter { get; set; }
        public DateTime? date { get; set; }
        public List<Author> author { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string confidentiality { get; set; }
        public List<Section> section { get; set; }
        public Patient patient { get; set; }
        public List<ConsentingParty> consentingParty { get; set; }
        public List<Action> action { get; set; }
        public object organization { get; set; }
        public string policyRule { get; set; }
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        public string clinicalStatus { get; set; }
        public string verificationStatus { get; set; }
        public Practitioner practitioner { get; set; }
        public Relationship relationship { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string mode { get; set; }
        public OrderedBy orderedBy { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class FhirNhs111InboundMessageRegistration
    {
        public string resourceType { get; set; }
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public Identifier identifier { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Section
    {
        public List<Section> section { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
        public Text text { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class ServiceProvider
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Source
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string endpoint { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Subject
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class SupportingInfo
    {
        public string reference { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Telecom
    {
        public string system { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string use { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Text
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string div { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Type
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public List<Coding> coding { get; set; }
    }


}
```

I was expecting by this, issue may be resolved but it could not.
When I have empty class, I can post message manually to my azure service bus queue, and I am able to consume message. But getting error if we push message by Nhs 111 test suite.`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the way your library is sending messages to Azure Service Bus, using an unsupported body type in the raw AMQP message. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654619/azure-service-bus-interoperability-between-apache-camel-based-producer-and-net) to understand why the Azure .NET SDK is unable to handle the message body when it isn't a binary byte array.

I don't know of a workaround, other than to change the library so that it sends a binary byte array instead of a sequence or other body type.